# Passing integer through a pipe

Tags: c++, linux

I have problem sending an integer or array of integer through a pipe n Linux, first I was trying to send an integer, look at this code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int count = 10 ;
    //cout <<"Enter a digit : ";
    //cin >> count ;
    cout<<"\n";

    int pfd1[1];
    pipe(pfd1);    

    int a=fork();
    if(a==0)
    {    
        close(pfd1[0]);
        write(pfd1[1],&count,sizeof(count));
        close(pfd1[1]);
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {   
        wait(NULL);
        int n =0;
        close(pfd1[1]);       
        read(pfd1[0],&n ,sizeof(n));
        close(pfd1[0]);
        cout <<"N from parent = "<<n<<"\n\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
N from parent = 4
```

The output should be `10` same as the one declared, but it gives me `4`, and even if I un-comment the comment code so the user enter a number, the output is always `4`, while it should be the number which the user entered.

What is wrong here? And what if I want to send array of integers?

Comment: Why are you ignoring `read()` and `write()` return value?

Comment: because i don't know what to do with them, i am still learning Linux.

Comment: do `man read`, `man write` in **terminal**, it will display what the return value means

Comment: Ok, i will give it a shot.

Comment: Also note: Neither read/write guarantee the number of bytes actually read/written is the same as the amount requested. You should check to make sure the everything you need has been written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going out of array bounds, you should declare `pfd1` as

```
int pfd1[2];
```

Comment: I have spent one hour trying to figure what is wrong , thx mate solved !

Comment: what if i want to send array of integers ? is it possible through pipe ?

Comment: @M.Sherin sure, write whatever you want to one end and read it from another end.